# asp FileUpload in content page not working due to updatepanel in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a master page where an update panel contains the main placeholder of the content pages.

Inside one of the content pages I need to disable the update panel in any way since I have a form with asp:fileupload control that is always returning null due to the update panel.

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your fileuploader and submit button in another update panel and add a post back trigger for this update panel.

Answer (score 1):

On page load of content page, try to get the update panel of master page using FindControl method and then attach your file upload as a post pack trigger to it dynamically.
That may work

Answer (score 0):

I've got a bad news for you.!

Have a look at this

http://ajax.asp.net/docs/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx

The following ASP.NET controls are not compatible with partial-page updates, and are therefore not supported inside an UpdatePanel control:

`TreeView` and `Menu` controls.

Web Parts controls. For more information, see ASP.NET Web Parts Controls.

`FileUpload controls` when they are used to upload files as part of an asynchronous postback.

`GridView and DetailsView controls` when their EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks property is set to true. The default is false.

```
Login, PasswordRecovery, ChangePassword, and CreateUserWizard controls
```

whose contents have not been converted to editable templates.

```
The Substitution control.
```

Validation controls, which includes the BaseCompareValidator, BaseValidator, CompareValidator, CustomValidator, RangeValidator, RegularExpressionValidator, RequiredFieldValidator, and ValidationSummary control.

**Solution :**
You may want to use [Ajax FileUpload using Jquery](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/satisharveti/ajax-file-upload-using-jquery/) in place of update Panel. Remember, Open source is always a better option. :)